# Putting a Laravel site on a Synology NAS (DS215j)

Tags: laravel, http-status-code-404, nas, synology

I've created my first full Laravel tool. (Yiehaaa).
I'm looking to host it somewhere for my customer as he wants to be able to use it from different PC's in his network.

Therefore I was thinking to put it on a Synology NAS (DS215j) which is already available.

I took following steps :

1. Install WebStation
2. Install PHP7
3. Install Nginx with MariaDB10
4. Imported all tables

My Webstation is up-and-running, telling Nginx is running with PHP7.

Under PHP settings, I enabled : mysqli, openssl and pdo_mysql.

In the end, I created a Virtual host PORT based (on port 85 for http and port 86 for https) and connected the main folder to "web/maintoolfolder/public".

As http back-end server Nginx is chosen, with PHP 7.0

When I now open following url http://nasname:85 , I get to see my index.php page without any problem ! So yeahhhhh...

But, whatever link I click which needs to open one of my routes, I always get the error message "404 page can not be found".
Strange thing is that this 404 page is not even the own created Laravel 404 page.

What am I doing wrong ? Why can't I move between the different pages?

Thanks in advance for any help.

best regards,

Davy

Comment: Please provide your Nginx configuration. It seems you forgot to include the `location\/ {try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;}` part for your vhost config

Comment: Javi, we changed this in the vHost file. But after a restart of the Nginx server, it changed back to original. We supposed Synology did it automatically ?

Comment: Javi, in which folder and which file do I need to add that line please?